# How to send mass emails from c# and check if they were delivered

Tags: c#, smtp

I need to implement the web application for sending marketing emails to the partners of the company. There are some requirements I have no idea how to solve it.

- The first one is how to check if the email was delivered? I'm sending emails through smtp server.
- The second one is how to check if the email was readed by receipient.
- the third one is how to ensure, that emails did not go to spam.

I'm using .NET platform.

I will apreciate any help to any of this questions.

thanks

Comment: Hi, depending on the recipient you can IMHO do neither. There used to be simple tricks to check for read (for example a image where you check if the image was beeing downloaded) but nowadays those things are frowned upon (THERE is something like privacy even in the US ;) ) ... all in all if your recipient don't like to cooperate your are out of options - to be honest I don't see why this should be so important unless you want to go email adress-fishing*

Comment: My email client is set to ignore the "read receipt" and "delivery receipt" flags, and also doesn't download any images until I tell it to. So you're out of luck if you're sending anything to me! Spam handling is VERY email client specific (or servers along the way) and many will silently dispose of the email. The last thing a spam handler wants to announce is that it's a live email address by saying to the spammer, "sorry, but your email wasn't delivered to fred@somewhere because I thought it was junk" as an intelligent spammer could try again in the knowledge that it *nearly* got through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I can think of is using what's often called a *tracking pixel* or *web bug* in your emails. Wikipedia has a comprehensive explanation of this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug.

However, it is easily bypassed.

Answer (score 4):

> - The first one is how to check if the email was delivered? I'm sending emails through smtp server.
> - The second one is how to check if the email was readed by receipient.
> - the third one is how to ensure, that emails did not go to spam.

TL;DR: You *cannot* do any of these using *standard* email protocols (ie. SMTP). There is no support in SMTP for acknowledgement or receipt or reading. There is no reliable mechanism to report failed to deliver: just ignoring is often done if determined to be spam.

Closed systems (eg. MS Exchange) can offer this kind of functionality where one organisation can set policies for all parts of the system end to end.

I suggest considering why [The Evil Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit) ([RFC 3514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3514)) is not an effective security measure.